# Undefined Angular DI variables when calling a method using a passed function reference

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular. I have a class that has a number of DI variables. Under normal execution of a method inside of the class the methods work properly and I am able to access the injected instances of the DI variables.

However I am attempting to create a generic modal that will display error text to the user if a particular function of the app fails. Within the modal an option to retry their last action will be supplied. I figured that by passing a reference to the method that the user last attempted and hooking it up to the onclick of a button I should be able to create the retry function that I've described. It does work, and the method in question is triggered when the user clicks the retry button. However the method itself causes an error as the DI variable being used within the method is undefined.

I'm unsure why this is happening, is this a closure issue? Without passing in a reference to the dependency I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. Passing in a reference is something I obviously don't want to do as it'll go against making the modal generic.

```
/*
* This is the method that the user initially triggers and the method who's 
* reference is passed to displayGenericModal if the method fails. 
* this._classSandbox.loadClasses(); contains a HTTP request which is why it might fail
*/
syncClasses() {
    this.syncingClasses = true;
    this._classSandbox.loadClasses(); //this._classSandbox is the DI variable that is undefined upon execution of the method from the generic modal.
  }

  displayGenericModal(errorKey: string, retryFunction: Function, retryParams: any[]) {
    this._genericErrorModal.open(this._dialog, {
      errorKey: errorKey,
      retryFunction: retryFunction, //This is a reference to syncClasses()
      retryFunctionParams: retryParams
    });

  }

/*
* This service is referenced by the this._genericErrorModal variable 
*/ 
export class GenericErrorModalService {

  constructor() { }

  public open(dialog: MatDialog, params: GenericErrorModalParams) {
    dialog.open<GenericErrorModalComponent, GenericErrorModalParams>(GenericErrorModalComponent, {
      data: params
    })
  }
}
```

So just for clarity, upon the first execution of the `syncClasses()` method, everything works correctly. If the HTTP request inside this method fails, a reference to this method is passed to the `GenericErrorModalService.open()` method. When the modal itself is opened and the retry button (which holds the reference to the `syncClasses()` method) is clicked, the method fails because `this._classSandbox` is undefined.

Comment: When you pass the last executed method to your service, you need to bind your component otherwise the execution context will be different, hence `this` will not be what you expect. Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind)

Comment: @Florian So something along the lines of `this.syncClasses.bind(this)`?

Comment: yes if you are in the component of `syncClasses` method !

Comment: @Florian Worked perfectly thanks, if you want to provide an answer I'll select it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing `syncClasses` in a different context. When you *retry* you call the method from a different component, hence `this` is different.

What you want to do is binding `this` to your component when you pass the reference to your service.
In your main component when you pass the refence, use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
this.syncClasses.bind(this)
```